# Better way of opening a Document from Java?

Tags: java, windows, process

I've been using the following code to open Office Documents, PDF, etc. on my windows machines using Java and it's working fine, except for some reason when a filename has embedded it within it multiple contiguous spaces like "File[SPACE][SPACE]Test.doc".

How can I make this work?  I'm not averse to canning the whole piece of code... but I'd rather not replace it with a third party library that calls JNI.

```
public static void openDocument(String path) throws IOException {
    // Make forward slashes backslashes (for windows)
    // Double quote any path segments with spaces in them
    path = path.replace("/", "\\").replaceAll(
            "\\\\([^\\\\\\\\\"]* [^\\\\\\\\\"]*)", "\\\\\\\"$1\"");

    String command = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c start " + path + "";

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);            
}
```

**EDIT:** When I run it with the errant file windows complains about finding the file.  But... when I run the command line directly from the command line it runs just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Java 6 you can just use the [open method of java.awt.Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)) to launch the file using the default application for the current platform.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you much... I use java 1.5+'s [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)  to launch external shell scripts in a java program.  Basically I do the following: ( although this may not apply because you don't want to capture the commands output; you actually wanna fire up the document - but, maybe this will spark something that you can use )

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add(someExecutable);
command.add(someArguemnt0);
command.add(someArgument1);
command.add(someArgument2);
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
try {
final Process process = builder.start();
...    
} catch (IOException ioe) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be the "start" command you are using, rather than your file name parsing. For example, this seems to work well on my WinXP machine (using JDK 1.5)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

public class test {

    public static void openDocument(String path) throws IOException {
        path = "\"" + path + "\"";
        File f = new File( path );
        String command = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c " + f.getPath() + "";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);          
    }

    public static void main( String[] argv ) {
        test thisApp = new test();
        try {
            thisApp.openDocument( "c:\\so\\My Doc.doc");
        }
        catch( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm you are using C:\\so\\My[space][space]Doc.doc right?